# uc before sort in map

Tags: perl

```
map{ chomp; $isword{uc join "", sort /./g} .= "$_+" } <FH>;
```

Generally, it uses items in file, first sort, then uc, then add to hashmap.

But I want to first uc, then sort.

Does any one know how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

In keeping with the spirit of terseness you have achieved:

```
map{ chomp; $isword{join "", uc =~ sort /./g} .= "$_+" } <FH>;
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use 5.10.1;
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my %isword;
map{ chomp; my $c=$_; $_=uc$_; $isword{join "", sort /./g} .= "$c+" } <DATA>;
say Dumper \%isword;
__DATA__
cbA zyx
DEF tuv
Ghi PQr
```

#### Output:

```
$VAR1 = {
          ' GHIPQR' => 'Ghi PQr+',
          ' DEFTUV' => 'DEF tuv+',
          ' ABCXYZ' => 'cbA zyx+'
        };
```